# Ruby save modified array in a variable without it changing the original array

Tags: arrays, ruby

I'd like to save in two variables the values of an array excluding the first and last elements.

For example:

```
prices = [9, 3, 5, 2, 1]
```

The elements I need are:

```
prices_excl_first = [3, 5, 2, 1]

prices_excl_last = [9, 3, 5, 2]
```

I figured out how to remove an element from an array a few ways, including slicing off the value by passing its index to the slice method like so:

```
first_price = prices.slice(0)
last_price = prices.slice(-1)
```

We could then save the modified arrays into variables:

```
array_except_first_price = prices.delete(first_price) #=> [3, 5, 2, 1]
array_except_last_index = prices.delete(last_price) #=> [3, 5, 2]
```

There are two problems with this:

1. array_except_last_index doesn't contain the first element now
2. I still need access to the full, original array `prices` later

So essentially, how can I just temporarily modify the elements in the array when necessary in the problem?

Slicing and dropping elements from array permanently affect the array.

Comment: Perhaps [`Array::first`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Array.html#method-i-first) and [`Array::last`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Array.html#method-i-last).  Each method takes an optional parameter.

Comment: To be clear, if it were `prices = [5, 5, 10, 10]` you want `[5, 10, 10]` and `[5, 5, 10]`? That's dropping the first and last *element*. Or do you want `[10,10]` and `[5,5]`? That's dropping the first and last *value*.

Comment: @orde Thanks for directing me! I got it now since I can get the total length of the array and that can be passed into the first and last methods.

Comment: @Schwern I would like to drop the first and last elements. That's a great point you make with duplicate values though!

Comment: @user9503053 may I ask _why_ you want to exclude the first / last price? Do they have special meaning?

Comment: @Stefan Each price is associated with a day and [the problem](https://www.theodinproject.com/courses/ruby-programming/lessons/building-blocks?ref=lnav) requires buying before selling, so I was trying to remove the first price/day from potential sell days. I was removing the last price/day from potential buy days, since you wouldn't be able to sell if you bought on the last day. I ended up going about the problem a little differently though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ruby has [`first`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Array.html#method-i-first) and [`last`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Array.html#method-i-last) to copy just the first and last elements.

Ask for the first and last `prices.size-1` elements.

```
prices = [9, 3, 5, 2, 1]
except_first = prices.last(prices.size-1)
except_last = prices.first(prices.size-1)
```

Answer (score 4):

@Schwern's answer is probably the best you can get. Here's the second best:

```
prices = [9, 3, 5, 2, 1]
prices[1..-1] # => [3, 5, 2, 1]
prices[0..-2] # => [9, 3, 5, 2]
```

Or `drop`/`take` (which more closely map to the wording of your question).

```
prices.drop(1) # => [3, 5, 2, 1]
prices.take(prices.size-1) # => [9, 3, 5, 2]
```

Comment: Worth noting that the `drop` / `take` approach is nice in that it can be made lazy very easily. `prices.lazy.drop(1)` in Ruby 2.0+

Comment: Sergio, I don't see how your #1 solution can be improved upon. It's immediately understandable what you are doing, no calculation is involved and it's supported by versions of Ruby that are as old as the hills.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: "immediately understandable" only if you've seen with range-taking array indexer in the past (and know about negative indexes). I honestly think that first/last is more understandable to a beginner. I myself would use range if I had to drop the last element, and `drop` if I had to omit the first.

Comment: Casting back to when I was teaching myself Ruby I recall covering `Array#slice` very early on and thinking it was pretty cool. Others may have had a different experience, of course.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`each_cons`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_cons):

```
a, b = prices.each_cons(prices.size - 1).to_a
a #=> [9, 3, 5, 2]
b #=> [3, 5, 2, 1]
```

Comment: plus 1 for cleverness and only one-liner.

Answer (score 2):

Splat it.

```
*a, d = prices                                                
c, *b = prices

a #=> [9, 3, 5, 2]
b #=> [3, 5, 2, 1]
```

Comment: You could also use of the special `_` variable name instead of `d` and `c`...ruby doesn't complain if you don't make use of it (`ruby -w -e "def splat_it; prices = [9, 3, 5, 2, 1]; *a, _ = prices; p a; end; splat_it"` = no warnings, whereas you get warnings if you use `d`); though if you need/want to use `d` elsewhere you would ignore this comment.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dup` to duplicate the array before performing destructive operations.

```
prices = [9, 3, 5, 2, 1]

except_first = prices.dup
except_first.delete_at 0

except_last = prices.dup
except_last.delete_at -1
```

This does end up duplicating the array a couple of times. If you're dealing with large arrays, this may be a problem.